# String view in c++

Tags: c++, string, substring

I am interested to view a part of string. I have an example code below. Actually I am interested to view substring of string, for example from index 1 to 5 or 0 to 7 or so. I have `.substr()`, but I want to avoid the copying. How can I do that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <experimental/string_view>

int main()
{
  std::string name;
  name = "Hello world";
  std::experimental::string_view name_v (name);
  std::cout << "string view, " << name_v << "!\n";
}
```

Comment: Which copying actually? Isn't `std::string_view` exactly designed for that?

Comment: See the constructors here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I mean if I use `.substr()`, it creates a copy, to avoid that, there is `string_view`, where I am not able to view a substring. How to view a substring by `string_view` based on index.

Comment: There is no `substr()` in your code. Pls show your actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [std::experimental::string_view::substr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view/substr) it creates a new [string_view](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view) without copying any of the string itself:

```
      std::string name = "Hello world";

      std::experimental::string_view name_v (name);

      std::cout << "string view, " << name_v << "!\n";

      auto sub_v = name_v.substr(1, 4); // creates a new string_view

      std::cout << "sub view, " << sub_v << '\n';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does all standard library implementations  implement this `experimental` feature

Comment: @AwaitedOne Not yet but the feature is no longer `experimental`, it was accepted into `C++17` standard. So future compilers will **all** support it.